# Method that extends built-in class (through ".prototype" property of JS) isn't working when my Angular library project is started with "--prod" option

Tags: javascript, angular, built-in

I'm building an `Angular` library with the follow structure:

```
my-library-project
|_ dist
|_ e2e
|_ projects
  |_ my-library
    |_ extensions
      |_ number
        |_ src
          |_ lib
            |_ extension.ts
          |_ index.ts
          |_ ng-package.json
          |_ package.json
          |_ public-api.ts
    |_ src
      |_ test.ts
    |_ index.ts
    |_ karma.conf.js
    |_ ng-package.json
    |_ package.json
    |_ public-api.ts
    |_ tsconfig.lib.json
    |_ tsconfig.spec.json
    |_ tslint.json
|_ src
```

Inside `extension.ts` there is a follow code:

```js
export { };


declare global {

    interface Number {

        isOdd(): boolean;

    }

}

Number.prototype.isOdd = function(): boolean {

    return (this % 2) !== 0;

};
```

I perform `$ ng build my-library` and I import `my-library/extensions/number` in a component and I write `console.log((2).isOdd())` inside the constructor body. I perform`$ ng s` and until here all it's ok, but if I perform with `--prod` option `Number.prototype.isOdd()` doesn't exist, so the browser throws a error, as we can see in its inspect.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare it as a interface. You can go with a simple class and add your method isOdd there.

The difference is interface aren't present or exported in built versions where as classes are, which in fact minimises the file sizes too.

## Edit

Define a class like below. Here isOdd method would be available. Interfaces don't get exported and are more for defining types, where as in classes you can define the behaviour. Read more about interfaces and class in typescript here https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/interfaces.html .

```js
export class MyClass {
  public isOdd(): boolean {
    // your code
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand.

Comment: I have edited my answer to define a class. Try by defining a class and not an interface. Classes implement interfaces and interface are more for defining types and not concrete behaviours.

Comment: Yeap, interfaces are to just accomplish a contract at time of transpilation from ```TS``` to a valid ```JS```. But the ```declare``` statement is to inform to ```TS``` transpiler that the declaration truly exists in ```JS```. In my case it's implemented in the same file. I need that. I want to add a instance method on ```JS``` built-in ```Number``` class.